# Radeon R9 280 graphics card isnt installing in 15.04

Tags: 15.04, opengl

I have `fglrx-updates` installed but `fglrxinfo` shows

```
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.5.2


stephen@Hopkins-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall fglrx
[sudo] password for stephen: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bbswitch-dkms iucode-tool libcuda1-340 libjansson4
  libvdpau1 libxnvctrl0 nvidia-prime
  screen-resolution-extra
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/37.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 181925 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../fglrx_2%3a15.200-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fglrx (2:15.200-0ubuntu4) over (2:15.200-0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for systemd (219-7ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Setting up fglrx (2:15.200-0ubuntu4) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...

    stephen@Hopkins-PC:~$ lspci -k | grep VGA -A2
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti PRO [Radeon HD 7950/8950 OEM / R9 280]
    Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. Device 3003
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti XT HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7970 Series]

stephen@Hopkins-PC:/etc/modprobe.d$ ls
alsa-base.conf               blacklist-watchdog.conf
alsa-base.conf M-A           dkms.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf       fbdev-blacklist.conf
blacklist.conf               fglrx-core.conf
blacklist-firewire.conf      intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
blacklist-framebuffer.conf   iwlwifi.conf
blacklist-modem.conf         mlx4.conf
blacklist-oss.conf           modesetting.conf
blacklist-rare-network.conf  vmwgfx-fbdev.conf

stephen@Hopkins-PC:/etc/modprobe.d$ cat blacklist.conf
This file lists those modules which we don't want to be loaded by
alias expansion, usually so some other driver will be loaded for the
device instead.
evbug is a debug tool that should be loaded explicitly
blacklist evbug
these drivers are very simple, the HID drivers are usually preferred
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
replaced by e100
blacklist eepro100
replaced by tulip
blacklist de4x5
causes no end of confusion by creating unexpected network interfaces
blacklist eth1394
snd_intel8x0m can interfere with snd_intel8x0, doesn't seem to support much
hardware on its own (Ubuntu bug #2011, #6810)
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
Conflicts with dvb driver (which is better for handling this device)
blacklist snd_aw2
causes failure to suspend on HP compaq nc6000 (Ubuntu: #10306)
blacklist i2c_i801
replaced by p54pci
blacklist prism54
replaced by b43 and ssb.
blacklist bcm43xx
most apps now use garmin usb driver directly (Ubuntu: #114565)
blacklist garmin_gps
replaced by asus-laptop (Ubuntu: #184721)
blacklist asus_acpi
low-quality, just noise when being used for sound playback, causes
hangs at desktop session start (Ubuntu: #246969)
blacklist snd_pcsp
ugly and loud noise, getting on everyone's nerves; this should be done by a
nice pulseaudio bing (Ubuntu: #77010)
blacklist pcspkr
EDAC driver for amd76x clashes with the agp driver preventing the aperture
from being initialised (Ubuntu: #297750). Blacklist so that the driver
continues to build and is installable for the few cases where its
really needed.
blacklist amd76x_edac
```

Comment: Did you install fglrx?

Comment: Now it looks OK. Please reboot and add output of `lspci -k | grep VGA -A2` to your question too.

Comment: Probably previously installed nvidia drivers may interfere. Run `sudo apt-get purge nvidia* && sudo apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: Now reboot and see `lspci -k | grep VGA -A2`. You can replace the previous output. If it still does not work run again `sudo apt-get install --reinstall fglrx` and reboot.

Comment: I see that fglrx module still does not load. It either does not support this card or is blacklisted. Look into all files in `/etc/modprobe.d` if there is `blacklist fglrx` line.

Comment: I searched the net and found that it is always trouble with this video card. I do not have any more ideas so far.

Comment: Did you look into `blacklist.conf`?